# Why does Karma show nothing?

Tags: karma-jasmine

Pretty much the title. I've been experimenting with Karma/Jasmine and this keeps happening. Sometimes there are errors in the console, sometimes not. Sometimes I add a blank line or two and it starts working. Sometimes I have to restart the `ng test` command and it starts working. It seems 90% of the time it has nothing to do with any actual fault in my test code. What does this blank screen mean? Have the tests not been run?

[image]